# RabbitMQ with pika: different callback for different queue on same channel?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have a hard time understanding the basic concepts of RabbitMQ. I find the online documentation not perfectly clear.

So far I understand, what a channel, a queue, a binding etc. is.

But how would the following use case be implemented:

**Use Case: Sender posts to one exchange with different topics. On the receiver side, depending on the topic, different receivers should be notified.**

So the following should somehow be feasible with a *topic exchange*:

- create a *channel*
- within this channel, create a *topic exchange*
- for each topic to be subscribed to, create a *queue* and a *queue binding* with this topic as property

My difficulty is that the *callback* would be related to the *channel*, not to the *queue* or the *queue binding*. I am not 100 % sure if I am right here.

So that's my question: in order to have multiple callbacks, IOW: different message handlers, depending on the subscribed topic - do you have to create *multiple channels*, one for each "different message handling"? All these channels should grab the same exchange and define their own queue + queue binding for that specific topic?

Please confirm if this is correct or if I am straying from the canonic path of AMPQ ... "queue" sounds so light-weight, so I intuitively thought of a queue or a queue binding as the right point to attach a consuming event handler to, but it seems that, instead, channel is my friend in this. Right?

**Another aspect of my question:**

If I really have to use multiple channels for this, do I have to declare the same exchange (exchange name and exchange type of "topic") for each channel? I hoped there was something like:

- define the exchange with this name and the type of "topic" *once*
- for each channel, "grab" this predefined exchange and use it by adding queues and queue bindings to this exchange

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to think about the roles of the broker (RabbitMQ) and the clients (your applications) separately.

The broker, RabbitMQ, will receive messages from your publishers, route them to queues, and eventually send them to consumers.  The message routing can be simple or complex.  In your case, the routing is topic based with a few different queues.

You haven't said much about the publishers, likely because their job is simple.  They send messages with a routing key to RabbitMQ.

The consumer side is where things can get interesting.  At the simplest level, a consumer subscribes to a queue, receives messages from RabbitMQ, and processes them.  The consumer opens a connection to RabbitMQ and will use a channel for a particular use (e.g., subscribing to a queue).  The power of message brokers is that they allow designers to break up processes into separate apps if desired.

You don't give much insight into your application, other than the presence of different message topics.  An important design choice for you to make is how to define the application(s).  Are the different topics suitable for separate applications, or will a single application handle all types of messages.

For the former case, you would have one application for each queue.  A single channel that subscribes to the queue is probably the most sensible decision unless your application needs to be threaded. For threaded applications, each thread would have its own channel and all threads can be subscribed to the same queue.  Each application would have its own callback function for processing that type of message.

For the latter case (single application with multiple queues), the best approach would be to have at least one channel per queue.  It sounds like each queue would require its own callback function, and you would assign the functions to the channels according to its subscription.  You might have multiple channels per queue if your application can process multiple messages (of each topic) simultaneously.

Regarding your question about declaring exchanges, queues, and bindings, these items only need to be created once.  But it is reasonable practice to have your clients declare them at connection time.  Advantages of declaring them are that they will be created again if they were deleted and that any discrepancies between your declaration and what is on the broker will trigger errors.